# Using terraform in gitlab file getting error

Tags: gitlab, terraform, var

I want to pass variables gotten from gitlab to my terraform. I can see gitlab getting the vars but it errors out at the terraform apply/

In my gitlab file i have

```
    - echo "$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
    - echo "$GITLAB_USER_NAME"
    - terraform apply --auto-approve -var branch_name=$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG -var branch_creator=$GITLAB_USER_NAME
```

in my terraform i'm setting branch_name and etc as variables

i keep getting this error in my gitlab build

```
Failed to load Terraform configuration or plan: open "last name": no such file or directory
```

Comment: I don't suppose your gitlab user name ends with "last name"?

Comment: Could you share your terraform file?

Comment: I wasn't able to use the last name and the only reason i could come up with was that gitlab didn't like the space that occurs in GITLAB_USER_NAME as a result i changed it to GITLAB_USER_LOGIN(which doesn't have any spaces) and i'm still able to determine who created the branch although its not their actual name

Answer (score 0):

You could try again with [GitLab 13.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/10/22/gitlab-13-5-released/#get-started-quickly-with-gitlab-and-terraform) (October 2020)

> ### Get started quickly with GitLab and Terraform
>
> A new GitLab CI/CD template enables you to set up Terraform pipelines without any manual work, lowering the barrier to entry for your teams to adopt Terraform.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/infrastructure/) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/223131).

From that generated example, you can check if it includes a similar `terraform` call and compare it with your use-case.